# If I have a class called 'exceptions' and it has only static classes, is this breaking Java standards?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

If I have class like this, which is essentially just a package object, is it breaking standards to have it follow the package naming conventions? I thought I remembered reading this in the OCJP study guides. Seems logical but my co-worker called this out and I'm not sure if there is any official stance from oracle on this.

```
public class exceptions {

    public static class TemplateRenderException extends Exception {
        public TemplateRenderException(String message, Throwable e) {
            super(message, e);
        }
    }

    public static class UnmarshallingException extends Exception {
        public UnmarshallingException(String message, Throwable e) {
            super(message, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read Oracle's stand on this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html).

To sum it up, if you want to group a series of classes and don't need to use private methods of the nested classes nesting static classes is fine, the section [Why use nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaoo/nested.html) talks about using nested classes if it makes sense for encapsulation and readability reasons.

There is no say about the naming standards, but my understanding is it's not correct, as a class should always start with a capital letter

Comment: okay thanks, so the outer class should basically be called Exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

> If I have class like this, which is essentially just a package object, is it breaking standards to have it follow the package naming conventions?

Yes. It's not a package, it's a class, so it should follow class naming conventions... or better yet, just make it a package instead, given that it sounds like you want it to *act* like a package. That's if you really and truly think it's a good idea to have a clustering like this for exceptions, rather than putting them in the package where they're most relevant - the latter is what I'd do, personally.

Comment: These are indeed packaged where they are relevant. Rather than creating a bunch of files, my intention is to simplify the code by placing all of the exceptions for this composite object in one file in the relevant package. This is very much borrowing from scala's terse and flexible file and packaging rules to create a simpler project.

Comment: @JasonG: So *all* you're saving is having several files - at the cost of having a class which is meant to look like a package (but will behave like a class). Do you really have *that* many exception classes that they're causing a problem? It seems unlikely that the downside in terms of convention-breaking is worth the dubious benefits.

Comment: @JasonG IMHO having lots of simple files makes each one simpler.

Comment: I would probably have agreed if I had only ever been a java developer. IMHO having fewer bits floating around in a project is simpler and simpler is better. It's a matter of opinion rather than fact though so I understand everyone will have a bit of a different stance. With quite a bit of scala experience under my belt, I definately feel the standards embraced in scala make a more maintainable project and I find myself flexing Java in ways I otherwise wouldn't have to try to ease project navigation.

Comment: PS yes I will not break the naming convention now - I appreciate the feedback.